# Debugging link error with lib.a file

Tags: c++, build, compilation, linker, linker-errors

The project I'm working with, uses the VTK (ver 5.8.0), c++ 4.6.3, buntu 12.04
The code compiles w/o any errors.  The linker is failing with: **undefined reference to QVTKWidget2::QVTKWidget2(QWidget*, QGLWidget const*, QFlags)**
This class is in `VTK/GUISupport/Qt/QVTKWidget2.cxx`   As far as I can tell, this is in **libQVTK.a**  (`grep -i -l QVTKWidget2 *.a`) or **libQVTK.so**, **libQVTKWidgetPlugin.so** (`grep -i -l QVTKWidget2 *.so`)  But I'm not sure a text search is enough to say the reference/symbol is there.  I'm not sure what the linker is looking for.
When I try to locate the symbol w/ `nm -A *.a|grep QVTKWidget2` the five responses are too cryptic for me to understand.  (I'm not sure what to look for.)
When I look at the .so files (`ldd libQVTK.so`), I see references to different libs, and no mention of QVTKWidget2.    (Further confusion.)
The linker cmd is `/usr/bin/c++`  The library is called explicitly with `/full/path/to/VTK/build/bin/libQVTK.a`

Edit 1:
In this case a simple text search is not good enough.  `grep -i -l QVTKWidget2 *.a` will flag **libQVTK.a**  When taking a closer look at the archive `ar -t libQVTKA.a`, this lib contains **QVTKWidget.cxx.o**  There is no mention of **QVTKWidget2.cxx.o**.  I'll guess this is due to name mangling, or just the archive format.

Edit 2:
`nm -C libQVTK.a | grep QVTKWidget2` returns nothing.  `nm -C libQVTK.a |grep QVTKWidget` shows there is only QVTKWidget class members in this archive.  `nm -C libQVTK.so | grep QVTKWidget2`, again returns nothing, while `nm -C libQVTK.so | grep QVTKWidget` shows only QVTKWidget class members.  The results are the same for **libQVTKWidgetPlugin.so**  Again, due to name mangling, a text search is misleading.

Is there a quick way to find out which library has the QVTKWidget2 class?  (QVTKWidget2.cxx.o)

Comment: use `nm -C` to demangle the C++ names, like this: `nm -C /full/path/to/VTK/build/bin/libQVTK.a | grep QVTKWidget2::QVTKWidget2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the QVTKWidget2 class was not being built.  It is only built when the OpenGl stuff is built.  Which is controlled by the CMAKE flag: VTK_USE_QVTK_QTOPENGL  (on)
(I really really hate CCMAKE.)